# How does a ring affect an inverse rotor?

Tags: enigma

Rotor I with ring A would look like this:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
EKMFLGDQVZNTOWYHXUSPAIBRCJ
```

Inverse rotor I with ring A would look like this:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
UWYGADFPVZBECKMTHXSLRINQOJ
```

Rotor I with ring B would look like this:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
FLNGMHERWAOUPXZIYVTQBJCSDK
```

Am I right that inverse rotor I with ring B will look like this?

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
JUWYGADFPVZBECKMTHXSLRINQO
```

Comment: Checked only a few. Seems ok. It is just the inverse of the permutation.